# aggregate function within server function in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to apply the `aggregate` function within `server` function in shiny:

```
library(data.table)

datT2<-fread(paste0('C:/data/','30092017ARB.csv'),header=TRUE, sep=";",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#datT2[is.na(datT2)]<- 0

function(input, output) {

  #read the data 
  dataset <- reactive({
    infile <- input$date
    if (is.null(infile)){
      return(NULL)
    }
     data<-read.table(paste0('C:/data/',infile),header=TRUE, sep=";")
     data[is.na(data)]<- 0
#

     if (input$konz != "All") {
       data <- data[data$Konzernbezeichnung == input$konz,]
     }
        # Aggregate
    data<- aggregate(x=data$'EL absolut',by=list(lgd=data$`LGD-class`),FUN=sum)
            })



  # 
  # Filter data based on selections
  output$plot <- renderPlot({

    y <- dataset()$x #Marktwert #EL.absolut
    barplot(y,names.arg = dataset()$lgd)

  })

 }
```

When I run the same `aggregate` function in the shell I get

```
  lgd        x
1   1   385668
2   2   249534
3   3 35477549
4   4  2248865
5   5  1425647
```

I tried even `aggregate.data.frame`however, I get in both cases the following error:

```
Warning: Error in aggregate.data.frame: no rows to aggregate
```

or

```
Warning: Error in aggregate: no rows to aggregate
```

A sample data set is:

```
Konzernbe  Best  LGD-class  Marktwert   EL absolut 
6010    3   3   1142345261  1428757
6010    3   3   849738658   1028973
6010    1   3   1680222820  220554
6010    1   3   896459567   116673
6010    0   3   1126673222  72077
6010    1   3   704226037   93310
--      1   4   336164879   49299
6010    0   3   948607746   60443
6070    1   3   265014117   34170
6020    3   3   47661945    58551
6050    2   3   307011781   115959
6020    0   1   1064022992  20320
6010    0   3   831782040   52950
6080    3   3   19367641    20286
--      2   4   197857365   87608
6010    1   3   679828856   90884
6050    3   3   317092037   372362
6080    3   3   20223616    21929
6010    1   3   693736624   96899
6050    3   3   308447822   372915
```

How can I solve the problem?
Could it be that one has to use another method to aggregate within shiny-server?

Comment: Are you sure that `data` was read in correctly? You should check what `data` looks like after `read.table`

Comment: I am roughly sure, that the 'data' is read correctly, because if I use 'hist' and without aggregate, it works!

Comment: Your server code reads `LGD-class` but in the sample data it is `LGD.class`

Comment: @GregordeCillia: you are right, I correct it. However, the problem is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function(input, output) {

  #read the data
  dataset <- reactive({
    infile <- input$date
    if (is.null(infile)){
      return(NULL)
    }

    data<-read.table(paste0('C:/data/',infile),header=TRUE, sep=";")
    data[is.na(data)]<- 0

    if (input$konz != "All") {
    data <- data[data$Konzernbezeichnung == input$konz,]
    }

    # Aggregate
    data<- data[,list(ELAbsolut=sum(`EL absolut`)),by=`LGD-class`]

  })

    # Filter data based on selections
    output$plot <- renderPlot({

     y <- dataset()$ELAbsolut
     barplot(y,names.arg = dataset()$`LGD-class`)

    })

  }
```